# How to get `access_token` for my application?

Tags: support, api

I have an application that queries the public SO APIs.  Specifically, I take in an id and get the metadata of the question.  I am currently doing this via unauthenicated GET requests so I am hit by the 300 requests per user limit.

I'd like to get the 10,000 limit but I don't have 'Users' to authenticate.  My users don't need to have SO accounts so I can't just have them go through the OAuth flow.  Is there some sort of token I can pass with the GET requests to identify that my app is making the request and get a higher limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register for an application-specific API token at the [StackApps.com site](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register):

> Upon registering, you'll be provided an API key which grants your app a much larger per-day request quota than using the API anonymously.

The registration link is listed on the homepage, in the sidebar, together with the API documentation link and a link to manage any applications you have registered.

Incidentally, StackApps is *also* the place to get support for API questions. See the [StackApps On-Topic help page](https://stackapps.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question is about …
>
> - the Stack Exchange API
> - applications built on the Stack Exchange API
> - scripts or browser extensions that work with Stack Exchange sites …    it is welcome here.